# DLL load fails at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, json.net

I have a c# application that I can run just fine locally.  It is dependent upon many other c# projects.  When I right click and publish and get the setup.exe, once I run that I get an error stating

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>   File name: 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'

This is specifically coming from my Twitter project. The twitter project does not reference 4.5.0.0 it references 6.0.0.0

I cannot seem to find any references to 4.5.0.0 anywhere.. I am using tweetsharp-unofficial 2.3.1.2 ( https://github.com/timothy-makarov/tweetsharp ) which itself has a json.net dependency but nothing I am explicilty referencing.

Any clues as to how this is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This happens a lot when different projects reference different versions of the same nuget package. One of the projects that your Twitter project references must be using 4.5.0.0

Comment: If all the projects are in the same solution, you can open the nuget package manager and go to the Consolidate tab and it show mismatched versions.

Comment: @GBreen12 I don't agree with your statement. *"This happens a lot when different projects reference different versions of the same nuget package"*.  This is run-time error and it can happen independently if nuget used or not. May be you referring to a case, when one project refs v1 of dll and also refs second project, which in turn, refs v2 of same dll. In this case, error would say something about 2 different versions. If projects not connected, the one that builds last will simply overwrite dlls in bin and error will happen at runtime, as it is here. A lot depends on circumstance here.

Comment: @GBreen12 My twitter project doesn't reference any other projects except one, which is just models, and doesn't even have newtonsoft in that project.  It does have one nuget package installed and one class/interface file I made for the service.

Comment: Also I now updated every version to be 6.0.0.8
No change in the error calling for 4.5.0.0

Comment: Usually doing what @Jonathan said works. I don't understand all the ins and outs of Nuget, but from what I understand basically it tells your code "When you are looking for Newtonsoft.Json, If you have any version between 0 and 6, just use 6 instead"

Answer (score 1):

Further to what GBreen says above, depending on the level of control you have over references, you can also look at bindingRedirects in your `web.config`. SOmething like follows:

```
<!-- Upgrade of NewtonsoftJson.dll to version 6.0.2. The Web API/MVC 4 has been built with version 4.5 of NewtonsoftJson.dll, so we need a redirect in the web.config for now.-->
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here what this error means:

You built a DLL using Newtonsoft assembly with higher version than the one that you have in your bin. Assembly version is written into your DLLs manifest.  During the load, if the version of assembly in bin is lower, it throws that exception. Additionally, only 3 digits do matter in version (`a.b.c.x`) - `a`, `b` and `c`. For example, versions `1.0.0.1` and `1.0.0.2` are interchangeable. If you built DLL against v6.0.0.0 and placed in bin v4.5.0.0, you will have an issue. But opposite should work, only as long as you don't call some methods that changes signature, or the methods you call don't call other methods that changes signature.

1.
Best solution is to unify versioning - use same version everywhere.

2.
If you use higher version DLL in bin, it should work even for apps that are built using lower version of same dll

3.
Or, you can add version redirection to your app.config. This specific config redirects higher version build to use lower version. It will work as long as no new functions are called

```xml
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" appliesTo="v1.0.3705">  
    <dependentAssembly>   
      <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture=""/>  
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="4.5.0.0"/>  
    </dependentAssembly>  
  </assemblyBinding>  
</runtime>
```

BTW, at this time newtonsoft current version is 9+

Comment: Hm.  I updated all the projects to use 6.0.0.8, it still gives the same error though when running about not having 4.5.0.0.
I also tried #3, but in my app.config if I put that runtime it doesn't generate a .config file for me.  (I know that works for web.config is the app.config placement different?)

Comment: @JordanBrooklyn now that all your projects ref v6.0... run app with no `assemblyBinding` in `config`. IF that doesn't work... If you have trouble adding this to app.config (see if you already have `<runtime>` in config then add only inner content), you always can add it directly to your `myApp.exe.config`. Only this time you need to change to `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.8"/>`. You have 3rd party that may reference v4.5 and have set for "specific version". Do what I say, let me know. HEY, and just make sure that dll in bin indeed v6

Comment: I did try again.  The moment I add that block to my app.config (under the configuration tag, in my console apps app.config) when I publish I no longer get a 
```CacheConsoleApp.exe.config.deploy```
It's not even in the manifest.  If I comment out that runtime tag I get the config again.  Any thoughts as to why this would be happening?

Comment: @JordanBrooklyn no idea. Try to add section post-build.